# EF Core - how to model relation of Grandparent - Parent - Child on same model

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Imagine a model of `User` that can have `Parents` and also can have `Children`.

How would you model such a case in EF Core?

I tried with something like that (pseudo-code)

```cs
public class User 
{
   public ICollection<Relation> Relations {get;set;}
   public ICollection<User> Parents => Relation.Where(r => r.Relation == 'Parents')
   public ICollection<User> Children => Relation.Where(r => r.Relation == 'Children')
}

public class Relaction
{
   public User User1 {get;set;}
   public Guid User1Id {get;set;}
   public User User2 {get;set;}
   public Guid User2Id {get;set;}
   public Relation Relation {get;set;} //some enum or sth to indicate relation type
}
```

But in such modeling, I'm not able to force EF DbContext to fetch into User.Relations data where UserId is in User1Id and in User2Id.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is a classic many-to-many self relationship - (1) user as parent can have many users as children, and (2) user as child can have many users as parents.

Thus it is modelled with one main entity and one join (linking) entity similar to what you have shown. The linking entity does not need special indicator because the two FKs determine the role. i.e. lets change your example with more descriptive names:

```cs
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class UserRelation
{
    public User Parent { get; set; }
    public User Child { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
    public Guid ChildId { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in pseudo code, given `User user`, then

```cs
user.Parents = db.Users.Where(u => user == u.Child)
user.Children = db.Users.Where(u => user == u.Parent)
```

EF Core 5.0+ allows you to hide the join entity (it still exists, but is maintained implicitly) and model the relationship with the so called skip navigations, which are the natural OO way of representing such relationship, e.g. the model becomes simply

```cs
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; }
    public ICollection<User> Parents { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Children { get; set; }
}
```

This is all needed to create such relationship.

However the name of the join table and its columns by convention won't be what normally you would do - in this case, they would be "UserUser" table with "ParentsId" and "ChildrenId" columns.

If you use migrations and don't care about the names, then you are done and can safely skip the rest.

If you *do* care though, luckily EF Core allows you to change the defaults with fluent configuration (even though in a not so intuitive way):

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Parents)
    .WithMany(e => e.Children)
    .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>("UserRelation",
        je => je.HasOne<User>().WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("ParentId").IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict),
        je => je.HasOne<User>().WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("ChildId").IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict),
        je => je.ToTable("UserRelations")
            .HasKey("ParentId", "ChildId")
    );
```

Here `Dictionary<string, object>` is the shared type EF Core will use to maintain the join entity in memory (change tracker). And is the most annoying thing in the above configuration since in a future they might change their minds and use different type (there are actually plans to do that in EF Core 6.0), so you'll have to update your mappings. Note that this does not affect the database design, just the memory storage type in EF Core change tracker.

So, because of that and the fact that in some scenarios it is better to work directly with the join entity, you could actually combine both approaches (explicit join entity and skip navigations) and get the best of both worlds.

To do than, you add the explicit entity and (optionally) navigations from/to it. The next is w/o collection navigations from `User` to `UserRelation` (with fully defined navigation you would need *two* `ICollection<UserRelation>` properties there):

```cs
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; }
    public ICollection<User> Parents { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Children { get; set; }
}

public class UserRelation
{
    public User Parent { get; set; }
    public User Child { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
    public Guid ChildId { get; set; }
}
```

and *required* minimal fluent configuration

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Parents)
    .WithMany(e => e.Children)
    .UsingEntity<UserRelation>(
        je => je.HasOne(e => e.Parent).WithMany(), // <-- here you would specify the corresponding collection nav property when exists
        je => je.HasOne(e => e.Child).WithMany(), // <-- here you would specify the corresponding collection nav property when exists
        je => je.ToTable("UserRelations")
    );
```

The result is the same database model, but with different in-memory representation of the join entity and ability to query/manipulate it directly. Actually you can do the same with implicit entity, but in type unsafe way using sting names and object values which need to be cast to the appropriate type. This probably will improve in the future if they replace `Dictionary<string, object>` with some generic type, but for now explicit entity combined with skip navigations looks the best.

You can find (I guess better than mine) explanation of all this in the official EF Core documentation - [Many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) and the whole [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) section in general.